# Easiest way to make snow covered leaves?

Tags: modeling, cycles-render-engine, texturing, uv, displacement

I'm making a winter scene and there are lots of trees. I need them all to be snow covered, while having some areas still green. So far, the only thing i have found online is this: http://thomas-cairns.com/TreeTutorial.html but it seems like a lot of work and i feel there might be an even easier way..Not to mention i have a lot of trees so baking might not be the best option. Anyone have any ideas how i can pull this off?

[image]

Comment: There is an add-on https://www.blendernation.com/2015/12/12/blender-market-snowfx-dynamic-snowtool/ or here is something similar to your https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/4907/how-to-create-piles-of-snow-on-a-mesh but anyway I guess you use particle System to generate trees so you would have to crate a separated group of objects (trees) to be generated in some areas or fake it by shader based on object location (it depend on what details of trees you need.

Comment: Maybe the Real Snow-add on is something for you? https://3d-wolf.com/products/snow.html

Comment: It could be possible to duplicate leaves, join them into one object and extrude a bit upwards, then scale to give them impression of thickness. Or maybe make all leaves as collision object, add multiple meshes with active rigid body and snow material and run simulation (this one is much more resources-hungry)

Comment: @vklidu hmm, I could randomly select some leaves and scale them/rotate, then add a snow material, but it won't look good because it will be flat, and i cant affords to use any subdivision surface (in reference to the second link)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone in the future who has the same problem as me, I ended up using a node setup to create the snow effect, which with some tweaking was the solution (credit to jeremy from the blender discord for this setup)

The Node setup:
[image]

If you want to use displacement (HIGHLY SUGGEST TO USE ADAPTIVE SUBDIVISION)

[image]

Also, here are some guides i have found useful and also will work as alternatives.

http://thomas-cairns.com/TreeTutorial.html

The answer by risingfall: [How to add snow to a plant](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/95220/how-to-add-snow-to-a-plant)

[How to create piles of snow on a mesh?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/4907/how-to-create-piles-of-snow-on-a-mesh)

An addon that could be of use: https://3d-wolf.com/products/snow.html

Was creating semi-low poly trees that were gonna be viewed from a distance and was getting frustrated. glad the node setup worked! it looks 100x better with adaptive subdivision, but for background trees for my scene it wasn't needed.

My result:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Is this something you are looking for?

**Conifer trees - shader**
[image]

**Conifer trees - mesh** - [3DM Snow add-on](https://github.com/3DMish/Blender-Add-ons-3DM-Snow)
[image]

**Deciduous tree - mesh** - select one top face, *Select Similar > Normal* (Shift+G), Separate > Selected (Ctrl+P), add modifiers Solidify, Remesh, Subsurf, Remesh, Solidify

[image]

[image]

[image]